# Is there a notion of Lucas/Fibonacci sequences beyond adding two numbers at a time, if so where could I read more about that?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, recurrence-relations, golden-ratio

So I recently learned about lucas/fibbonaci sequences EG; 1,1,2,3,5,7 or 3,4,7,11,18... A fact I learned about these sequence is that the limit of the quotient of the terms approaches the golden ratio (1.61803398874989484820). What I found independently (somewhat) was that this ratio could also be understood as the root of the polynomial $x^2-x-1$(this can be derived from the geometric definition of the golden ratio).

In trying to understand the golden ratio further, I extended the notion first by finding a new version of the fibbonaci sequence starting with three terms. 1,1,1:3,5,9,17,31,57,105... The ratios of this sequence converge to roughly 1.83, which is also one of the real roots of the polynomial $x^3-x^2-x-1$. At this point, I'm pretty sure that's an obvious pattern.

After I found the ratio for the 3-fibbonaci/lucas sequence I began to wonder what the ratio of an inifnite version of this would converge to (if at all). So I wrote out a general notation for a sequence where you add up n terms starting with (x0,x1,x2,,,,,,xn). The first term of the sequence is the summation from k=0 to n or "X sub K." The second term is the earlier term plus the summation from k=1 to n. As you write out the terms, you can show that the ratio of the terms converges to 2.

Lastly, does this imply that 2 is the root of the polynomial $x^n-x^{n-1}....-x-1?$

Comment: That's some nice exploratory work there. You'll enjoy reading about characteristic polynomials of [linear recurrences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients). "*...converges to $2$*" The root is not exactly a $2$ though it gets closer to $2$ the larger $n$ is.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that what I'm talking about isn't really a polynomial lol. It's more accurate to say that when you take polynomials of this form, one of their real roots approaches 2. What I know is I've found a relationship between notions of the golden ratio, polynomials of the above form, and a new type of lucas sequence. I'll need to look at this some more! thanks for the link bro.

Comment: You might also look at this page on generalizations of the Fibonacci numbers. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#N-generated_Fibonacci_sequence

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation

Answer (score 3):

Nice work!

You have discovered linear recurrence relations. The place to start reading is wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

The infinite recurrence you specify does have growth rate $2$ because the $n$th term is $2^{n-1}$ but $2$ is not a root of the polynomials you specify since each expresses just a part of the recursion. For that, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: Yeah, I'm realizing it's not accurate to say this polynomial has 2 as a root: because it's not a polynomial! It's more accurate to say that when you look at the roots of polynomial of the form x^n-x^n-1...-x-1 that no root can exceed the value of 2 and the values seem to approach as you increase the number of terms. I just finished calc 2 so I'm very new to this more abstract side of math, and thanks for the links bro!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question independently of what you wrote following it, I think that what you  are interested in is the Binet equation (see, for example, [Fibonacci Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)). The closed form solution for the Fibonacci numbers is given by

$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}$$

and that for the Lucas numbers is given by

$$L_n=\varphi^n+\psi^n$$

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $\psi=1-\varphi$ is its complement.